# Floating div left but no more text below it?

Tags: html, css-float

Here is my css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .column_n {
        margin: 20px;
        float: left;
        width: 250px;
    }
</style>
```

The problem is I get a column in the left of the page. But after the element on the leftside finished, the text on the other div starts filling below it. Something like this:

```
xxxxxx yyyyyy
xxxxxx yyyyyy
xxxxxx yyyyyy
xxxxxx yyyyyy  
yyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

What I want is:

```
xxxx yyyy
xxxx yyyy
xxxx yyyy
     yyyy
     yyyy
```

How Can I accomplish this?

Thank you!

Html code:

```
<div class="column_n"> 
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
</div>
<div> 
    yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 
</div>
```

Comment: please add html for the above example

Comment: <div class="column_n">
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
</div>
<div>
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this:

.column_n {
        margin: 20px;
        float: left;
        width: 250px;
    }

.column_b {
        left: 290px;
        position: absolute;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Updated to use inline as suggested by Roy, however you'll need to use display:inline, rather than display:inline-block;

A demo here : http://tinkerbin.com/VAEFGoBm

Try this :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .column_n {
        margin: 20px;
        display:inline;
        width: 250px;
    }
 .column_b {
        margin: 10px;
        display:inline;
        width: 250px;
    }
</style>

<div class="column_n"> 
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
</div>
<div class="column_b"> 
    yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set this -

```
display: inline-block;
```

For **both** columns.
using float: left might not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="column_b"> 
    yyyyy yyy yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy    ssssssssss sssssssssssss
</div>
<div class="column_c"> 
    ddddddddddd dddddddddd dddddddda assssssssssss
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .column_c {
     width:100px;
    background-color:red;
overflow:hidden;
   float:left;
    }
 .column_b {
   float:left;
          width:100px;
overflow:hidden;

    background-color:blue;
    }
</style>
```

here's a jsfiddle of what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/YDFLV/62/

Comment: but i want the column on the left to be fixed size, the one on the right responsive?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .column_n {
        margin: 20px;
        float: left;
    }
    div{
        width: 250px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TeMWS/1/